# Read from file with BufferedReader

Tags: java, bufferedreader, java-io

Basically I've got an assignment which reads multiple lines from a .txt file. 
There are 4 values in the text file per line and each value is separated by 2 spaces.
There are about 10 lines of data in the file.

After taking the input from the file the program then puts it onto a Database. The database connection functionality works fine.

My issue now is with reading from the file using a BufferedReader.
The issue is that if I uncomment any 1 of the 3 lines at the bottom the BufferedReader reads every other line. And if I don't use them then there's an exception as the next input is of type String. 
I have contemplated using a Scanner with the .hasNextLine() method.

Any thoughts on what could be the problem and how to fix it?
Thanks.

```
File file = new File(FILE_INPUT_NAME);
FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
BufferedReader readFile = new BufferedReader(fr);
String line = null;
while ((line = readFile.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] split = line.split("  ", 4);

    String id = split[0];
    nameFromFile = split[1];
    String year = split[2];
    String mark = split[3];

    idFromFile = Integer.parseInt(id);
    yearOfStudyFromFile = Integer.parseInt(year);
    markFromFile = Integer.parseInt(mark);

    //line = readFile.readLine();
    //readFile.readLine();
    //System.out.println(readFile.readLine());
}
```

Edit: There was an error in the formatting of the .txt file. a missing value.
But now I get an ArrayOutOfBoundsException.

Edit edit: Another error in the .txt file! Turns out there was a single space instead of a double. It seems to be working now. But any advice on how to deal with file errors like this in the future?

Comment: In your while loop you are reading one line at -a-time into the variable `line` which is then being `split` into `id`, `namefromFile`, `year` and `mark` - why are you trying to further read `line` within the loop - this is duplicate

Comment: Please provide more details on the method that has the code you posted. Does it throw an `IOException`? What kind of data are you reading from the .txt file? Are they 4 tokens (string or number) per line? The 3 commented out lines most probably should stay commented out. :-)

Comment: The file has the information: id (Student's ID), name, year of study, and mark (out of 100)

Comment: Just realised that there was a formatting issue inside the txt file! So the casting error is gone, but now there's an ArrayOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: @JacobO update your answer with the full errors, which you're currently having.

Comment: for a start change `String[] split = line.split("  ", 4);` to `String[] split = line.split("  ");`

Comment: I think I've got it working now! And I have changed that Wombat.

Comment: You were probably trying to read an empty line at the bottom. You should put your BufferedReader on a Try and Catch block. Also you can eliminate the last line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A compilable version of the code posted could be

```
  public void read() throws IOException {
    File file = new File(FILE_INPUT_NAME);
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader readFile = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String line;
    while ((line = readFile.readLine()) != null) {
      String[] split = line.split(" ", 4);
      if (split.length != 4) { // Not enough tokens (e.g., empty line) read
        continue;
      }
      String id = split[0];
      String nameFromFile = split[1];
      String year = split[2];
      String mark = split[3];

      int idFromFile = Integer.parseInt(id);
      int yearOfStudyFromFile = Integer.parseInt(year);
      int markFromFile = Integer.parseInt(mark);

      //line = readFile.readLine();
      //readFile.readLine();
      //System.out.println(readFile.readLine());
    }
  }
```

The above uses a single space (`" "` instead of the original `"  "`). To split on any number of changes, a regular expression can be used, e.g. `"\\s+"`. Of course, exactly 2 spaces can also be used, if that reflects the structure of the input data.

What the method should do with the extracted values (e.g., returning them in an object of some type, or saving them to a database directly), is up to the application using it.

Comment: Thanks, I've found the error which turned out to be in the file it was being read from. And the way I read from the file is a double space as the name field works like "Bob B", so the firstname and lastname are together on the same field.

Comment: You definitely need to make sure that you do something if not exactly 4 tokens are read. Plus numerous other things for error handling. Happy coding! :-)

Comment: Thank you! I'm already doing exceptions, but yeah, less than 4 tokens is definitely a priority fix!

Answer (score 1):

> The issue is that if I uncomment any 1 of the 3 lines at the bottom the BufferedReader reads every other line.

Correct. If you put any of those lines of code in, the line of text read will be thrown away and not processed. You're already reading in the `while` condition. You don't need another read. If you put any of those lines in, they will be thrown away and not proce